# Black lines on texture

Tags: texturing

[image]

I have a problem with texture. I have some black lines and I do not know how to fix this. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by your brush being limited to the boundaries of the UV islands. You have 2 ways to fix that :

1. increase the Bleed value in the Tool Shelf > Options tab
2. paint on a transparent background and once you're done painting, save the image, import it in the compositor and feed it through an Inpaint node

the latter being the best in complex models and textures but in your case the first is certainly sufficient.

However no matter how simple or complex your model is, you always need margins between your UV islands, even bigger ones if you're using bleed since without a big enough margin it can overlap to another island (which doesn't happen with Inpaint but still a small margin is obligatory).

Comment: you're welcome. I added some important info, since looking at your UV map you don't have margins. If this answer solved your problem, you can accept it.

Comment: Glad to know it. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: some additional info on the bleed method here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78039/texture-paint-wont-paint-the-whole-face-bleed-option-seems-to-be-off/88454#88454